# Need to override windows default file.separator without changing java code

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, tomcat, ftp

Prod code runs on UNIX, but need to run local DEV on windows.

The current code gets a path in UNIX format from a DB then builds on that path using file.separator which adds windows separators causing the ftp to fail as path for target is formatted incorrectly. ex: `/incoming/ri-etl\DEV\Rulebooks/tate_rbid_1715_retest`

```
/incoming/ri-etl from a DB setting
```

`\DEV\Rulebooks` built in code using file separator.

Since other team uses MAC OS for Dev they do not see the issue locally. Tried to over ride the path.separator using `-DFile.Separator=\/` (and other variations) in **Tomcat ARGS**, **JAVA_OPTS** and **CATALINA OPTS** with no success.

I think if I can force the UNIX format Windows will accept it and FTP will work. FTP will not accept a path all built in the WINDOWS format.

I am running **TOMCAT** from within **ECLIPSE** (TOMCAT 8, Java 7, Eclipse MARS).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons comes handy in here:

`FileNameUtils.separatorsToSystem()` will do what you are looking for.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(FilenameUtils.separatorsToSystem("/incoming/ri-etl\\DEV\\Rulebooks/tate_rbid_1715_retest"));

}
```

Output(on mac):Converted **backslash** to **forwardslash**

```
/incoming/ri-etl/DEV/Rulebooks/tate_rbid_1715_retest
```

Comment: Thanks , but I cannot change the common code.  I need to find a way to override outside of the code base.